# White flickering when transitioning to a new screen and the background is a dark color?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, exponentjs

I am experiencing this when transitioning to one screen to another with two different navigators: ex-navigation and the new one React Navigation
. There is a white flickering for a second (or half a second). Looking for a solution I found that other navigators have the same problem. For example the navigator from wix 
[HERE](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/14). From the link:

> Ok, the problem is, that React styles applies after the navigation
>   started, and by default the backgroundColor is white, so this is the
>   flicker effect..

Someone having the same issue?

Comment: Solved with: https://medium.com/@Krizzu/how-to-change-background-color-of-rootview-in-react-native-3279417c34bb My TabNavigator was giving me a white flash before mounting my screens.

Answer (score 20):

I resolved the white flickering issue by setting the property in NavigationContainer of React-Navigation v5.

```
<NavigationContainer theme={{ colors: { background: '#000' } }}>
{...}
</NavigationContainer>
```

It helped me remove white flickering as I updated the color same as my background color BLACK.

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/380#issuecomment-748038449

Comment: However it does fix the issue, it deafults the otherwise white backgrounds to black.

Comment: Just spent hours on this, and your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, life saver, the solution also works fine with react-navigation  v6+

Comment: worked great, cheers

Answer (score 3):

For me this did the trick:

```
cardStyle: { opacity: 1 }
```

Example:

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Main: { screen: DrawerNavigator }
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        cardStyle: { opacity: 1 } // Prevent white flicker on Android when navigating between screens
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(RootNavigator);
```

Comment: Where you have added the cardStyle. (i.e) inside the navigationOptions or defaultNavigationOptions

Comment: I edited my answer to give an example. It's not inside navigationOptions.

Comment: The above not worked for iOS. Did you have any fix for iOS

Answer (score 2):

I know that I am posting way late here, but yeah if someone get help by this then it'll be worth it.

I also faced the same issue because I was using dark theme for my project and whenever the navigation happened a white screen flashed for some milliseconds.

I resolved this issue by adding the same theme background color to NavigationContainer theme prop like below

`<NavigationContainer theme ={{colors:{background: /*same background color of your project */}}}> .... </NavigationContainer>`

This solved my issue, hope it solves other's too.

Thank You..

Answer (score 1):

When use DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator, need:

```
cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
},
```

and need:

use [react-native-root-view-background](https://github.com/johniak/react-native-root-view-background) to setRootViewBackgroundColor('black')

Answer (score 1):

For people using expo, you also need to pass a [`backgroundColor`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#backgroundcolor) in your `app.json`. So you should set this to some dark color from your app's color scheme.

```json
// app.json

{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "backgroundColor": "#1a202c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Typescript `cardStyleInterpolator` function based on `scaleFromAndroid` to prevent the whitespace around the screen when switching the screens.

This function removes the `opacity: 0` and the end of transition and adds a `overlayStyle` to the border of the screen while switching beetween the screens.

Example:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false, /* Hide the header */
    cardStyleInterpolator: scaleCenterAndroidInterpolator /* Overrides the default cardStyleInterpolator */
  }}>
  ...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

```js
    const scaleCenterAndroidInterpolator = ({ 
        current, 
        closing, 
        next 
    }: StackCardInterpolationProps)  => {

        const { add, multiply } = Animated;

        const handleConditionalScale = (
            condition: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation, 
            main: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation, 
            fallback: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation) => (
                add(multiply(condition, main), multiply(condition.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [1, 0]
                  }), fallback))
            )

        const progress: Animated.AnimatedAddition = add(current.progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
          }), next ? next.progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
          }) : 0);

        const opacity: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation = progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 0.75, 0.875, 1, 1.0825, 1.2075, 2],
            outputRange: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        });

        const scale: Animated.AnimatedAddition = handleConditionalScale(closing, current.progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0.925, 1],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
          }), progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
            outputRange: [0.85, 1, 1.075]
          }));

        const overlayStyle: { opacity: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation } = {
            opacity: current.progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [0, 0.5],
                extrapolate: 'clamp',
            })
        }

        return {
            cardStyle: {
                opacity: opacity,
                transform: [
                    { scale }
                ],
            },
            overlayStyle
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. And it seems to me that there are two solutions to that.

- First solution comes from the [link](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/14) you share. Basically you can add a background color to your `Navigator` component.
- Second solution, which I applied to my project previously, is not an exact one but a workaround. I changed how `Navigator` component transitions screens back and forth by changing `SceneConfigs`, from `Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight` to `Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight`. So my `Navigator` component become something like;

  ```
          <Navigator
              ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
              configureScene={(route) => {
                  return {
                      ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight,
                      gestures: {}
                  };
              }}
              initialRoute={{
                  id: (Platform.OS === "android" || Platform.OS === "ios") ? 'splashscreen' : 'login',
                  statusBarHidden: true
              }}
              renderScene={this.renderScene}
          />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color in your navigator like this:

```
<
Navigator style={{flex: 1}} 
  transitionerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}} ...
```

Hope this helps-

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was setting the `layout` option. I am using `wix-react-native-navigation`:

```
    layout: {
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      componentBackgroundColor: "#000",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me.
For iOS, I changed the background color in AppDelegate.m

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; ---> changed this
} else {
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; ---> and this
}
```

For android: (It's not perfect, black screen is shown for a while after splash srceen. My theme was dark so, it was good to go.)
In MainActivity.java,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
SplashScreen.show(this, true); ---> added true here
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

In styles.xml,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey  just a simple solution add amination in user navigation stack
screenOptions={{  animation:'slide_from_right' }}